# What are the main differences between 3.5e and 4e of D&D

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons

I've been playing D&D 4e for a while, and I've been considering n getting 5e or 3.5, and what are the main differences between 4e and 3.5e? I know 4e is more combat orientated, is 3.5e that same way? Or is it more roleplay oriented?

Thanks!